# Adding weighted directed edges to the networkx plot with an arrow from source to destination

Tags: python, plot, graph, networkx, directed-graph

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'),('C','D'),('G','D')], weight=1)
G.add_edges_from([('D','A'),('D','E'),('B','D'),('D','E')], weight=2)
G.add_edges_from([('B','C'),('E','F')], weight=3)
G.add_edges_from([('C','F')], weight=4)



nodeopt = {
    'node_color': 'white',
    'node_size': 3500,
    'node_shape': 'o',
    'linewidths': 1,
    'edgecolors' : 'black'
}

label_opt = {
    'font_size': 13,
    'font_color' : 'black',
}

edge_opt = {
    'width': 3,
    'edge_color' : 'black',
    'arrowstyle' : '-|>',
    'arrows' : True,
    'arrowsize' : 12,
    'connectionstyle' : 'arc3,rad=0.2'
    
}


##FOR PRINTING WEIGHTS ON THE EDGES
edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
                 for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])

## EDIT THE EDGE COLORS 
red_edges = []
edge_colors = ['black' if not edge in red_edges else 'red' for edge in G.edges()]
#red_edges = [('C','D'),('D','A')]
#edge_colors = ['black' if not edge in red_edges else 'red' for edge in G.edges()]

## FOR CREATING LABELS OF THE NODES 
node_labels = {node:node for node in G.nodes()}; 


pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,**nodeopt)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=node_labels, **label_opt)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, **edge_opt) 

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)

pylab.show()
```

Hello above is the code I am working. I was able to get the weighted edges but for some reason my graphs are not shown as directed despite using "nx.DiGraph()", would anyone be able to help?

For the case of G.add_edges_from([('C','F')], weight=4), I want an arrow from node C to F with a weight 4

Comment: Could you please also include what `node_text_options` is?

Comment: @BenGrossmann
Sorry, it was the old name of the formatting dict for draw_networkx_labels, I have updated it now.

Comment: Getting rid of the node-size specification results in a figure that has arrows; it looks like the nodes are so big that they're covering the arrowheads.

Comment: It solved it thank you, BUT now my nodes are very small. Do you know if there is a way to "attach" the arrowheads always to the border of the node and not the center?

Comment: Found it, there is: On the draw_networkx_edges function there is a parameter to specify your node size. when you plug the same value to both, it fixes it!

Comment: Yes, that's what I just wrote in my answer. In any case, I'm glad your problem is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comments, the nodes are so big that they're covering the arrowheads. The way to accommodate is to use the `node_size` argument when drawing the *edges*, not just the nodes. In other words, you can get the arrows back if you add a line to `edge_opt`, as in

```
edge_opt = {
    'node_size': 3500,
    'width': 1,
    'edge_color' : 'black',
    'arrowstyle' : '-|>',
    'arrows' : True,
    'arrowsize' : 12,
    'connectionstyle' : 'arc3,rad=0.2'
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by referring to the library manual:
On the draw_networkx_edges function, there is a parameter to specify your node size. when you plug the same value into both, it fixes it!

```
  nodeopt = {
    'node_size' : 1400,
    'node_color': 'white',
    'node_shape': 'o',
    'linewidths': 1,
    'edgecolors' : 'black'
}

label_opt = {
    'font_size': 13,
    'font_color' : 'black',
}

edge_opt = {
    'width': 3,
    'edge_color' : 'black',
    'arrowstyle' : '-|>',
    'arrows' : True,
    'arrowsize' : 22,
    'connectionstyle' : 'arc3,rad=0.2',
    'node_size' : 1400
    
}
```